# SP16 - Cannot create Calculated column with Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016, calculated-column, addfieldasxml

**This XML syntax is working:**

```
$HolidayWorkID = "<Field Type='Number' 
  Name='HolidayWorkID' 
  DisplayName='HolidayWorkID 
  Group='Holidays' />"
```

**But this doesn't working:**

```
$HolidayReportMonth = "<Field Type='Calculated' 
                                    Name='HolidayReportMonth' 
                                    DisplayName='CustomMonth' 
                                    Group='Holidays' 
                                    ResultType='Text'
                                    <FieldRefs>
                                        <FieldRef Name='HolidayDateFrom' />
                                    </FieldRefs>
                                    <Formula>=MONTH([HolidayDateFrom])</Formula> 
                                />"
```

**Error message is:**

> Exception calling "AddFieldAsXml" with "3" argument(s): "Name cannot
>   begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 2, position
>   10."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this

```
$HolidayReportMonth = "<Field Type='Calculated' Name='HolidayReportMonth' DisplayName='CustomMonth' Group='Holidays' ResultType='Text'> <FieldRefs> <FieldRef Name='HolidayDateFrom' /></FieldRefs>  <Formula>=MONTH([HolidayDateFrom])</Formula></Field>"
List.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($HolidayReportMonth,$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
```

Because there are **child elements** Like `Formula` and `FieldRef`,  I think the issue in the `<Field>`, that should be surrounded with `>` after the `result type` then close it at the end with `</Field>`

---

> **Note:**  `Fields.AddFieldAsXml()` takes 3 arguments
>
> 1. `schemaXml` as String
> 2. `addToDefaultView` as Bool
> 3. `Options` as `SPAddFieldOptions` check [SPAddFieldOptions enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spaddfieldoptions.aspx)

---

**Alternatively**, you can add a new calculated column via PowerShell, try the below script

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell –ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Variables
$WebURL="http://your site"
$ListName="your List"
$CalculatedColumnName="HolidayReportMonth"

#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL

#Get the List
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

#Add new calculated column
$list.Fields.Add($CalculatedColumnName, "Calculated", $false)

#Get the column
$CalculatedCol = $List.Fields.GetField($CalculatedColumnName)
#Set Formula for calculated column
$CalculatedCol.Formula='=MONTH([HolidayDateFrom])'
$CalculatedCol.OutputType="Text"
$CalculatedCol.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

Read more: [How to Add Calculated Column to SharePoint List using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/03/add-calculated-column-to-sharepoint-list-using-powershell.html)

Comment: Тhank you @M.Qassas